# UIApplication network indicator color swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I need to change UIApplication network indicator color. It is black by default. I want white network indicator color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the one displayed in the status bar? 
You can enable or disable it:

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true // enable activity indocator
```

But you can't change its color. It is managed by the iOS and it should adapt automatically based on the color of the top bar.

Or are we talking about the UIActivityIndicatorView that can be added to any UIView? For the latter, you can change the style and the color, too. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for resposne Karoly. It is possible actually. I saw in Facebook application. I found, there are only two simple steps :)

Comment: Nope, it's not possible to change the color of the network indicator directly.
You are changing the status bar style, not the indicator. Just what I said:
"It is managed by the iOS and it should adapt automatically based on the color of the top bar."

Comment: Yeah. It's right Karoly. There is no property to change color. But changing status bar style helped me.

Answer (score 1):

We can change UIApplication network indicator color. In my case it was black. I needed white one. So These are two simple steps.

1) First set view controller based property to NO in Info.plist

> `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`

2) Changing status bar style which turns black indicator to white.

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```